# local notification sound doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have an application that fires a local notification with sound.

But when notification fires, it doesn't play sound if my app is running. Only when i close my application it plays a notification sound.

I want it to play sound even if application is running on phone.

Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // register for sending notifications
    let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    return true
}

var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
localNotification.alertBody = "Local notifications are working"
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually play sound with `didReceiveLocalNotification`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
 print("received local notification")

 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

 //Play sound
 let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("beep", withExtension: "wav")
 var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound)

 var alert = UIAlertView()
 alert.title = "Alert"
 alert.message = notification.alertBody
 alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")

 alert.show()
}
```

Comment: can i play a default notification sound here?

Comment: You may not. @mikle94 You have to add custom sound